# Where do form fields in ASP.Net MVC take their values from?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, forms

I understand that fields such as Html.TextBox() accept two values, the first one being the name and the second one being the value. And so does Html.TextArea(). But in a case where the form is submitted as AJAX and the div where the form is placed is replaced with a view from the server, the form fields insist on taking the previous values. An image is worth a thousand words:

[image http://img132.imageshack.us/img132/4171/aspnetmvcbug.png](http://img132.imageshack.us/img132/4171/aspnetmvcbug.png)

I've checked everything on the controller and the model and the image is from debugging the view itself. The model is empty but the fields generated from it take the value of the previous submission.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The postback data is held in the ModelState. The built in HtmlHelper methods will look for values stored in the model state based on the name of the form element when rendering their content.

Comment: Oh! So the model state is clean when not using AJAX because I redirect. Adding a ModelState.Clear() when the method is success fixed it. Is that the way to go or am I destroying the ModelState?

Comment: I'm pretty sure ModelState.Clear() is ok to use - I use it in a few places in my code. It will clear any validation messages from the ModelState as well as the pre-postback form values but as long as you are aware of that I think there's really no problem using it.

Answer (score 2):

Check the View.ModelState property. Forms can grab values from there in certain circumstances.

Comment: Yes, the problem was in the ModelState. Doing a ModelState.Clean() seems to fix the problem, but I'm not sure if I'm destroying the ModelState in the process.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an entry ViewData["Body"]?  MVC will also attempt to bind a control to a ViewData item based on the name.